# Underscore JS, find object which contains value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Im looking for a solution to find json object which contains a value in b. example: find objects which contain "jinx" in b.

sample data.
    [{
    id:1 
    a:"karma",
    b:["jinx","caitlyn","tristana"]
    },
    {....},
    {....}]

I understand underscore works better for key/value pairs but this would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear, sample data is a variable so what about sample_data[b].indexOf("jinx"), if it returns -1 it means b doesn't contain jinx

Comment: let me try that out and update. thanks

Comment: I've posted in answer what I mean :) because it might not be clear enough in comment :)

Comment: Marko, each array object is of the format "{ id:1 a:"karma", b:["jinx","caitlyn","tristana"] }". let me know if that helps.

Comment: tell me, is sample data first instance string equal to  "{ id:1 a:"karma", b:["jinx","caitlyn","tristana"] }" because if it's an object like you stated then it can't be created without , between 1 and a , what would it represent than.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you an array `out` of objects that contains all items from array `in` where `b` contains the element `jinx`:

```
var in = [...];

var out = _.filter(in, function(item) {
   return _.contains(item.b, 'jinx');
});
```

Comment: works, thanks! only complain is that it returns an array of objects and not just the object. any idea? response = [object] instead of just object.

Comment: If you are only interested in the first result, replace `_.filter` with `_.find`.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore.js has a `.contains()` method which could useful in this case. If you're only concerned with searching the `b` key of your object then the following would work:

```
var sampleData = { id:1, a:"karma", b:["jinx","caitlyn","tristana"] };

if (_.contains(sampleData.b, 'jinx') {
  // Found
} else {
  // Not found
}
```

Based on your comment here's a revised version. This uses the `.filter` method of Underscore to filter the array to those containing `jink` in the `b`-keyed array.

```
var sampleData = [
  { id:1, a:"karma", b:["jinx","caitlyn","tristana"] },
  { id:2, a:"karma", b:["kinx","caitlyn","tristana"] },
  { id:3, a:"karma", b:["linx","caitlyn","tristana"] },
  { id:4, a:"karma", b:["minx","caitlyn","tristana"] },
  { id:5, a:"karma", b:["ninx","caitlyn","tristana"] },
  { id:6, a:"karma", b:["jinx","caitlyn","tristana"] },
  { id:7, a:"karma", b:["pinx","caitlyn","tristana"] },
  { id:8, a:"karma", b:["qinx","caitlyn","tristana"] },
  { id:9, a:"karma", b:["rinx","caitlyn","tristana"] }
];

var findJinx = function(data) {
  return _.first(_.filter(data, function(item) {
    if (_.contains(item.b, 'jinx')) {
      return item;
    }
  }));
}

console.log(findJinx(sampleData));
```

Comment: that would work for a single object but i forgot to mention that my data is an array. var sampleData = [{ id:1, a:"karma", b:["jinx","caitlyn","tristana"] }, {...}, {...}]

Comment: works, thanks! only complain is that it returns an array of objects and not just the object. any idea? response = [object] instead of just object.

Comment: So you're only expecting to find a single instance of the word you're searching for? Meaning only one of the objects will contain 'jinx'

Comment: If you know only 1 object contains you can simply return the first element from the resulting array. I've updated the solution using Underscores `_.first` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `underscore`, you can use `_.each` to loop thru your list of objects, then use `_.indexOf` to check each `b array` in each object like so: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rkamelot6262/BwHxv/378/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer in pure js :

```
if(sample_data['b'].indexOf("jinx") != -1){
    console.log("Object in b contains jinx");
}
```

If you need to support older browsers you can use this polyfill

```
Array.prototype.indexOf || (Array.prototype.indexOf = function(d, e) {
    var a;
    if (null == this) throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    var c = Object(this),
        b = c.length >>> 0;
    if (0 === b) return -1;
    a = +e || 0;
    Infinity === Math.abs(a) && (a = 0);
    if (a >= b) return -1;
    for (a = Math.max(0 <= a ? a : b - Math.abs(a), 0); a < b;) {
        if (a in c && c[a] === d) return a;
        a++
    }
    return -1
});
```

EDIT :

Since you said your data look like this

```
data=[{ id:1 ,a:"karma", b:["jinx","caitlyn","tristana"] }, {1:2}, {1:2}]
//between 1 and a you forgot ,
```

Then what you use is

```
if(data[0]['b'].indexOf("jinx") != -1){
    console.log("Object in b contains jinx");
}
```